# Perform (on)Click on radioButton in PrimeFaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I've two Radio Buttons and one Textarea. I want to change the CSS of the Textarea when I click on one of the Radio Buttons; when I click on "Yes", I want to enable the Textarea, when I click on "No", I want to disable the area.
Here's the code of both elements:

```
<h:outputLabel for="data" value="Change Data" />
<p:selectOneRadio id="data" required="true" value="No">
   <f:selectItem itemValue="Yes" itemLabel="Yes" />
   <f:selectItem itemValue="No" itemLabel="No" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<h:outputLabel for="yesdata" value="Details to change data" />
<p:inputTextarea id="yesdata" />
```

First I added the jQuery `click()` event. But the problem is, when I add this to the `<ui:define name="scripts">` area, the code will appear before the body, so this won't work.
So I tried to add a `onClick` trigger to both of the *selectItem*'s, added a method to change the css and added it to the *scripts*-area. But when I took a look to the rendered sourcecode, there is no onClick added to the Radio Buttons.

So how can I performe jQuery actions over the Radio Buttons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *First I added the jQuery click() event. But the problem is, when I add this to the `<ui:define name="scripts">` area, the code will appear before the body, so this won't work.*

Just add `target="body"` to `<h:outputScript>` to get it to end up right before `</body>`.

```
<h:outputScript ... target="body" />
```

This works for both included scripts (good practice):

```
<h:outputScript name="onload.js" target="body" />
```

and scripts written directly in tag body (bad practice):

```
<h:outputScript target="body">
    alert('Hi');
</h:outputScript>
```

---

> *So I tried to add a onClick trigger to both of the selectItem's, added a method to change the css and added it to the scripts-area. But when I took a look to the rendered sourcecode, there is no onClick added to the Radio Buttons.*

There are 2 problems: first of all, it's `onclick`, not `onClick`. The `onClick` is invalid since HTML 4.01 since 1998 which is quite a time ago. Please pay careful attention to the age of the resources you're using to learn HTML/JSF/etc and make sure that those are not older than 1~3 years, otherwise be very very careful with it.

Secondly, the [`<f:selectItem>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/selectItem.html) does nowhere list the `onclick` attribute. It's therefore beyond me why you attempted to put it over there. The [`<p:selectOneRadio>` tag documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/selectOneRadio.html) lists the `onchange` attribute. You should have better luck over there.

```
<p:selectOneRadio ... onchange="alert(this.value)">
```

By the way, the usage of your `<p:selectOneRadio value>` is wrong. It should represent a binding to a backing bean property. But that's a different problem.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the easy and "pure JSF" way of achieving the requirement without the need for some JS/jQuery would be to just throw in a `<p:ajax>` which updates the textarea component on change and have the textarea component's `disabled` attribute to conditionally check the radio button's selected value:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="data" binding="#{yesOrNo}" required="true">
   <f:selectItem itemValue="Yes" itemLabel="Yes" />
   <f:selectItem itemValue="No" itemLabel="No" />
   <p:ajax update="yesdata" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:inputTextarea id="yesdata" disabled="#{yesOrNo.value != 'Yes'}" />
```

In this example, the textarea will be disabled as long as "Yes" is not selected.

Comment: `+1` for the `outputScript`-part. New for me! | `+1` for the `onclick` part. Don't realized this mistake. Actually I should know that | `+1` for the most important part of your answer. Sadly I can upvote you just once. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, see the updated answer for a JSF-only way without need for any JS/jQuery.

Comment: You sir are amazing! I really need to read more about the possibilitys with jsf / primefaces!